# Me regresa la fecha con hora

Tags: mysql, asp.net, phpmyadmin

tengo un detalle con un programa, estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en ASP.NET con MySQL, el detalle es que en mi tabla tengo un campo llamado fecha y es tipo de dato **DATE** y en visual Basic de igual puse que su textmode es **DATE** adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de llamarlo lo muestro en un gridview, pero me lo regresa con hora 12:00:00 a.m. y solo me interesa la fecha, uso este codigo para llamarlo

```
  try
        {
            string cmd = string.Format("select * from HISTORIAL_FALLOS order by IDS");
            DataSet dt = KeyConnection.Start(cmd);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('OCURRIO UN ERROR, CONTACTAR AL DESARROLLADOR');</script>");
        }
```

Y el resultado es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual manera en el textbox de la fecha tampoco me lo llena con el dato.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda:)

Answer (score 0):

Para formatear una fecha desde `mySql` y convertirla en formato DD/MM/YYYY, puedes usar la función `date_format` y pasarle tu campo de fecha.

```
SELECT date_format(FECHA, "%d/%m/%Y") AS FECHA_CON_FORMATO 
FROM HISTORIAL_FALLOS;
```

Presta atención a los modificadores **%d %m %Y**, pues son la clave para formatear la fecha tal como la deseas devolver. [En este enlace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) puedes consultar la lista de modificadores permitidos en `mySql`.